# canvas not redrawing correctly

Tags: android

I am writing a simple view that will show a dot, after some action, show the next dot.  The dots are on a vertical strip.  so I create a function that'll clear the strip.  then draw a circle at the position where I want the dot. the code segment is as followed.

```
private void clear_strip(){
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    m_canvas.drawRect( 0, 0,width/8, height, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
}

private void set_dot(){
    clear_strip();
    m_canvas.drawCircle(width/10, (int) (font_height*(scoreboard.current_batter_position()+0.5))/1, font_height/4, paint);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    set_dot();
    canvas.drawBitmap(m_bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
}
```

but one of the dot is just not updating.  It'll keep the old dot, skip that dot, then move to the next dot.  I tried to print out the position to logcat right before the drawCircle call, and the position is right, it's just not drawing (and not clearing as well)....please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You get a canvas to draw into passed into your `onDraw` method. But the point drawing code uses the canvas `m_canvas`. Pass the canvas as a parameter to your dot drawing code to fix that.

Comment: actually m_bitmap is associated to m_canvas.  I found the problem.  it was a logic problem that I was not updating that particular view at that dot...so